# Mining contiguous sequential patterns in R

Tags: r, data-mining, tm

I'm trying to mine contiguous sequential patterns that are frequent in the input data using R, but I can't quite figure out how to do so. I though using `tm` library should be the way.

For example, given this data:

```
A,B,A,C
A,C,A,B,A,B
B,A,A,C,D
```

... and `min_support = 2`, we should get `A,B`,`B,A`, `A,B,A` and `A,C` patterns.
Also, multiple appearances of a subsequence in a single sequence record shouldn't be counted (so `A,B` in the second line should be counted only once, so it's support equals 2, not 3). How can it be done using R? While trying to follow [this](https://rpubs.com/brianzive/textmining) guide (starting at "N-gram Dictionary"), I couldn't get N-gram Dictionary right.

Here is the code I got so far:

```
# dummy data
df <- data.frame(doc_id = c(1:3),
                 text = c('AAA BBB AAA CCC', 'AAA CCC AAA BBB AAA BBB', 'BBB AAA AAA CCC DDD'),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df_corpus <- tm::Corpus(DataframeSource(df))
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) {
    NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))
} 
bigram <- tm::TermDocumentMatrix(df_corpus, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer)) 
inspect(bigram)
str(bigram)
```

From my understanding, this code should create bigram (like it did in the linked article). What am I missing? R version 3.4.1.

Comment: are expecting "AAA BBB", etc? BTW, you are using tm:: in some calls and not in others. Do you actually have tm loaded and rweka for the bigramtokenizer?

Comment: yes, that's my expectation. When I pass the text into `Weka_control`, it gives me the right patterns. But it doesn't work with `TermDocumentMatrix` for some reason